# The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched using SignalR

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I deployed an MVC4 application (that uses SignalR) to a server. SignalR works fine when I run it on my dev machine but when I run it after deploying it to the server I get the following error. I think it has to do with something not having permissions to write to the Event Log. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564420/the-source-was-not-found-but-some-or-all-event-logs-could-not-be-searched) answer but those solutions did not work for me. Can someone shed some light?

> System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.FindSourceRegistration(String source,
>   String machineName, Boolean readOnly, Boolean wantToCreate)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(String source, String
>   machineName, Boolean wantToCreate)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.VerifyAndCreateSource(String
>   sourceName, String currentMachineName)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEvent(EventInstance instance,
>   Byte[] data, Object[] values)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEvent(EventInstance instance,
>   Object[] values)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType eventType,
>   Int32 id, String format, Object[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartbeat.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__1(String
>   key, ConnectionMetadata old)    at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.AddOrUpdate(TKey
>   key, TValue addValue, Func`3 updateValueFactory)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartbeat.AddConnection(ITrackingConnection
>   connection)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ForeverTransport.ProcessReceiveRequest(ITransportConnection
>   connection)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(HostContext
>   context)    at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Infrastructure.ErrorState.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Exception
>   ex)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallContextAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously) The Zone of the assembly that failed
>   was: MyComputer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Security.SecurityException when writing to Event Log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274018/system-security-securityexception-when-writing-to-event-log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing you can set an admin user as Identity of your application pool.
By default the value is `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.

[image]

If it works you should add permission for the `Network Service` and add it as user of your app pool. You should add permission to this user on this registry key :
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Security`

Comment: I tried that but I still get the same error. I also notice that when this error is generated, the app pool shuts down, so I always have to restart it.

Comment: Wait a minute, maybe I misunderstood your answer. But when I changed the app pool identity to NETWORK SERVICE and gave it Full Control permission to the above registry key, it worked. I always thought that the identity ApplicationPoolIdentity "uses" the NETWORK SERVICE account behind the scenes.

Comment: Sorry my answer is a little unclear(I ll update my answer when Im back at home) . Im glad that helped anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another fix for this is to run Visual Studio as Administrator.